# Emitting and receiving events with Socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to emit an event with socket.io on my Node Js server and receive it client-side but I can't get it to work.

This is my server code:

```
// require our dependencies
var express        = require('express');
var expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
var app            = express();
var port           = 3000;
var server         = require("http").Server(app);
var io             = require('socket.io')(server);


// use ejs and express layouts
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(expressLayouts);

// use body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json({extended : true}));

// route our app
var router = require('./app/routes');
app.use('/', router);


// set static files (css and images, etc) location
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// start the server
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('app started');
});
```

This is my routes.js code, where the magic should happen:

```
module.exports = function(io){
// require express
var express = require('express');
var path    = require('path');

// create our router object
var router = express.Router();


// export our router
//module.exports = router;

router.post("/", function(request, response) {
console.log(request.body); 
io.emit('getupdate',{hello:'world'});
});

// route for our homepage
router.get('/showevent', function(req, res) {
res.render('pages/showevent',{data:exportage});
});
return router;
}
```

While this is my client-side script:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
  socket.on('getupdate', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
</script>
```

On the routes.js file, to get the "io" variable i wrapped all inside a function.

I can't get the message emitted in case of a POST request on my client.

Could you help me to find the issue here ?

Comment: Try `io = require('socket.io').listen(server)`? I found that in some of my code and it worked

Comment: It doeesn't give any error but it doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// require our dependencies
var express        = require('express');
var expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
var app            = express();
var port           = 3000;
var server         = app.listen(port);
var io             = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

I am not sure if you have updated this in your own code, but this snippet should pass `io` to the router:

```
// route our app
var router = require('./app/routes')(io);
app.use('/', router);
```

Comment: Hello, it gives me an error of "cannot read property of 'apply' of undefined at ../../express/lib/router/index.js:635:15

Comment: It's a library file

Comment: Answers that have no explanatory text that describes what the problem was with the original code, but rather leave it to the reader to try to figure out what you changed, can always be improved by adding text that explains the problem.